# Which of the following is true for $0 < x < 1$ if $f''(x) - 2f '(x) + f(x) \geq x$ , $x\in [0, 1]$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow R$  be a function. Suppose the function f is twice differentiable, $f(0) =f(1) = 0$ and satisfies $f''(x) - 2f '(x) + f(x) \geq x$
, $x\in [0, 1]$.
 Which of the following is true for $0 < x < 1$ ?

1) $0<f(x)<\infty$

2) $-1/2<f(x)<1/2$

3) $-1/4<f(x)<1$

4) $-\infty<f(x)<0$

Source:IIT 2013

No idea how to relate the inequality with the options.Literally stuck.Help please!

Answer (score 5):

Let $g(x)=f(x)e^{-x}$. Then $g''(x)\geq x e^{-x} \geq 0$. Thus $g$ is convex, with value $0$ at $0$ and $1$. So  $g(x)\leq 0, f(x)\leq 0$, and 4 is correct in $]0,1[$.

Comment: How did you get g(x)?

Comment: $C.e^x$ is an obvious solution to the $f"-2f'+f=0$ . So you let "vary the constant" to study the equation $C(x)=f(x).e^{-x}$

Comment: $g$ is convex, and is $0$ at $0$ and $1$

Comment: The convexity inequalty says $f(x)\leq xf(1)+(1-x)f(0) \leq 0$