# Equation satisfying $f''(x)- 2f '(x) + f(x)\ge e^x$, $x \in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus

Let $f : [0, 1]\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ (the set of all real numbers) be a function. Suppose the function $f$ is twice differentiable, $f(0) =f(1) = 0$, and satisfies $f''(x)- 2f '(x) + f(x)\ge e^x$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Which of the following is true for $0 < x < 1$ ?

(A) $0 < f(x) < \infty$

(B) $-\frac{1}{2} < f(x) < \frac{1}{2}$

(C) $-\frac{1}{4} < f(x) < 1$

(D) $-\infty < f(x) < 0$

The official answer is (D)

How do I approach this question to arrive at a correct conclusion?
I used $f(x)=g(x)e^x$

$f'(x)=g(x)e^x+e^xg'(x)$

$f''(x)=g(x)e^x+e^xg'(x)+e^xg''(x)+g'(x)e^x$

How do I approach from here?

Comment: You can probably adapt the argument given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514566/which-of-the-following-is-true-for-0-x-1-if-fx-2f-x-fx-geq?rq=1).

Comment: @mattos it is mentioned $\ge x$ where as in actusl question it is $\ge e^x$

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi: You can apply the answer of that similar question almost verbatim. All that matters is that $f''(x)- 2f '(x) + f(x)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track! Using what you have from $f(x) = g(x)e^x$ or equivalently $g(x) = f(x)e^{-x}$, you can get that $$f''(x) - 2f'(x) + f(x) = g''(x) e^x$$

Since you know that this is greater than or equal to $e^x$, you have that $g''(x) \ge 1$. From this, you know that $g(x)$ must be convex, and since $g(0) = g(1) = 0$, it must be true that $g(x) < 0$ for $x \in (0, 1)$. Then since $f(x) = g(x) e^x$, $f(x)$ would be negative as well. Thus, $D$ is the answer.